# How to concatenate multiple columns into single value to display in a dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a date field that I populate a dropdownlist with. The date field is like this `2012-05-01 00:00:00` and I need the dropdown list to look like this `5/2012`. But to put a wrench in things, I need to pull the date apart before I put it back together again.

Specifically, I need to find all "distinct" months and all "distinct" years, but I only want to find the distinct year, if there is a datefield with a month for that year and vice-versa.

So I have the following data

Table: **budget**

```
id   Item   ItemDate
1     A     5/12/2012
2     B     5/14/2012
3     C     4/5/2012
4     D     4/7/2012
5     E     7/15/2011
```

So I want my dropdown list to show the following only:

```
5/2012
4/2012
7/2011
```

I have tried using

```
SELECT DISTINCT datepart(Month, ItemDate) + ' ' + datepart(year, ItemDate) As ddlList 
FROM Budget
```

but that adds the month to the year (5 + 2012 = 2017).

and then my asp

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddl1" runat="server" datasourceID="sqldatasrc" DataTextField="ddlList"></dropdownlist>
```

Any ideas? I'm not sure I'm going about this the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ASP.NET

If I remember correctly, I believe you can use the property `DataTextFormatString` available on the DropDownList control to format the boundfield values. You have to set the property to the value **`{0:M/yyyy}`**. Please make sure that the property is available. I couldn't find it in MSDN.

I could find only [**ListControl.DataTextFormatString Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextformatstring.aspx)

## SQL

You have to cast the `MONTH` and `YEAR` parts of the datetime field values to `VARCHAR` or string data type before concatenating those values.

#### Demo

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5353/2)

#### Script:

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT    CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, ItemDate) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + 
            CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, ItemDate) AS VARCHAR) AS ddlList 
FROM        dbo.Budget
```

#### Alternative way to write the same script:

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT    CAST(MONTH(ItemDate) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + 
            CAST(YEAR(ItemDate) AS VARCHAR) AS ddlList 
FROM        dbo.Budget;
```

#### Create and insert script:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Budget
(
     Id         INT         NOT NULL 
  ,  Item       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ,  ItemDate   DATETIME    NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Budget (Id, Item, ItemDate) VALUES
 (1, 'A', '05/12/2012'),
 (2, 'B', '05/14/2012'),
 (3, 'C', '04/05/2012'),
 (4, 'D', '04/07/2012'),
 (5, 'E', '07/15/2012');
```

#### Output:

```
DDLLIST
-------
4/2012
5/2012
7/2012
```